# this.pause is not a function

Tags: javascript

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
$('.video').hover(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();
        $(this).get(0).currentTime = 0;
    },2000);

});
```

});

Имеется список видео, не понимаю как решить проблему с this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.video').hover(function() {
    setTimeout((function(){
      this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();
      $(this).get(0).currentTime = 0;
    }).bind(this), 2000);
  }); 
});
```